# How to Open an Activity After Multiple Clicks?

Tags: java, android

So I have an App that switches between activities using the onClick() method. One click takes you from the main activity to activity 1-6. Upon clicking activity 1-6, it will take you back to the main activity. I need a method that will upon clicking the main activity 3 times, will take the user to another, custom, activity.

It's a simple process, but I haven't seen any questions like this here on stack overflow.

Comment: You can use a counter for storing the click count values....

Comment: Does the clicks have to be one after the other in quick succession or wait time is allowed between the clicks?

Comment: Thanks, guys. It's been a while since I've coded. I'll definitely use a counter.